# Connecting to Windows shared folders --> CIFS VFS Error 104 and Error 32

Tags: networking, server, samba, shared-folders, cifs

[image: FSTAB Configuration]

While I have a lot of experience with windows server, I am new to Ubuntu/Linux, so please forgive me if this is a very easy issue to solve.

I am running Windows server 2008 R2 on my main server with media stored on several raid arrays and shared via windows file sharing across my network.  I also run several virtual machines on this box via hyper-v, one of which is Ubuntu server 16.04 (command line only) and this particular VM runs my Emby media server.  The Ubuntu server connects to several of the windows shared folders via CIFS (see `/etc/fstab` configuration file above) and mounts automatically when the VM boots.

I set up the Ubuntu VM about 6 months ago and it worked perfectly until I started getting errors 2 weeks ago.  Now multiple shared files/folders drop out of view.  When I open up the ubuntu server via hyper-v I get two errors that repeat:

```
CIFS VFS: Error -104 sending data on socket to server
CIFS VFS: Error -32 sending data on socket to server
```

There is significant network traffic be directed towards the windows server machine and the Ubuntu virtual server has above average CPU usage.  When I reboot the error temporarily disappears but comes back after a few hours later.  I tried rolling the VM back to a clean install (circa October 2016) but after installing all the ubuntu/emby updates the problem came back.  When I try to run `sudo umount –a` I get several errors saying `target is busy`

It looks like CIFS is getting stuck in some sort of loop.  Can anyone provide some insight on why this is happening?  Let me know if there is additional information I can provide to help debug this.

Comment: Screen shot of the CIFS errors  [link] http://imgur.com/pAjQxO5

Comment: when did this problem start occuring? We have almost the same problem since last friday (after installing windows patchday updates on our server), except umount works for us. Windows 2008 R2, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, all the same.  
We also have noticed another fact: we mount two shares from different servers, both shares seem to disconnect simultanously but one share (from Windows 2012 R2) successfully reconnects, after that the mentioned errors 32 and 104 start appearing in samba log file. 
Could not fix it so far

Comment: Its hard to say for sure, it has definitely been at least 2 to 3 weeks since I noticed it. Unfortunately this is a personal server so I don't log into it regularly and only access the Ubuntu hosted resources when I travel.  I can look at my patch log, I don't review them so they are installed automatically.  I am starting to think the April patch update

Comment: *Ignore above*  Its hard to say for sure, it has definitely been at least 2 to 3 weeks since I noticed it. Unfortunately this is a personal server so I don't log into it regularly and only access the Ubuntu hosted resources when I travel.  I can look at my patch log, I don't review them so they are installed automatically.  I am starting to think a recent server 2008 R2 patch has changed something in Samba (WannaCry exploit?) on the windows side and now it is throwing the Ubuntu server into a loop.  That might explain why your windows 2012 server reconnects without issues.

Comment: ooks like it may be a linux kernal bug, I am also running 4.4.0.75.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1686099

Comment: currently i'm on 4.4.0-78. According to this thread, they already fixed it but there is no release yet. I will try the suggested "ls every 15 minutes" cronjob, while waiting for fix. Thank you for this link!

Comment: oh no, now i getting ````umount: dug: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```` for my windows 2012 R2 share. this is insane

Answer (score 1):

As no one have answered I'll post this, it works for me but does not look like a stable solution. My problem was a bit different, I could not mount at all but the error was the same.

Don't use the **`guest`** option.

If your fstab entry looks like this:

```
//server/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Try this:

```
//server/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs user=guest,pass=,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

It has the same functionality as the **`guest`** option.

Comment: You can see OP's fstab now. Seems this doesn't apply to their problem :(

Comment: Gotcha. I also use Hyper-V so it might be related to that somehow.

Comment: Since error messages were the same, your answer could help others searching for those errors

Comment: I ended up just nuking the virtual server and reinstalling/configuring Ubuntu from scratch.  I am still using the same fstab configuration as above, but haven't encountered this issue yet on the new install (its been up for 5 or 6 weeks)